# selecting from drop down list in selenium python

Tags: selenium

i'm trying to change the selection of the period in this page using python's selenium.
http://www.championsleague.basketball/18-19/game/1010/AEK-Hapoel-Jerusalem#|tab=play_by_play

any ideas how to do it?
thanks :)

Comment: please read: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the element (I guess you are talking about the quarter selection next to "Play by play") with this css:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#gamepage_playbyplay span.period_select").click()
```

And then waiting for and selecting the value "Q4", for example:

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#gamepage_playbyplay span.period_select option[value="Q4"]')))
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#gamepage_playbyplay span.period_select option[value="Q4"]')).click()
```

Comment: Thanks.
I get this error:
ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated

Comment: What element? `"#gamepage_playbyplay span.period_select"` or `'#gamepage_playbyplay span.period_select option[value="Q4"]'`? If it is the former, add `wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#gamepage_playbyplay span.period_select")))` on the previous line.